# Rpi3B I2C 50k bd interferencing 4 sensors, including AS3935 lightening detector problem

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi-os

I have four devices connected to a Raspberry Pi 3B via I2C - an SPS30 (dust), a BME280 (temperature, humidity, pressure), MLX90614 (sky temperature) and TLS2561 (light). They are connected to a junction box outside (cable lengths ~ 1m to 6m) which is connected to the Pi via a Cat 6 flat ethernet cable. Because of the SPS30, the baudrate is limited (`i2c_arm_baudrate=50000`).

Now, I wanted to add a CJMCU-3935 (AS3935) lightening detector. As a prototype, I connected directly to the Raspberry Pi (using a screw terminal to add it to the existing cables). The AS3935 can use different addresses, and I set it to 0x03.

This works when it is the **only** device on I2C - as soon as I connect the others, there appears to be some interference and I can't connect to any of them. `i2cdetect` shows the other devices - but for the AS3935, it shows not 0x03 but 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14.

How could I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Not Pi specific.